# WPF custom control is blank

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a simple custom control that extends `TextBox`.

I create it by `Add -> New Item... -> Custom Control` and I make some change on the code generated automatically. I change the base class of the `CustomControl` into `TextBox` and delete the `Template` setter in `Theme/Generic.xaml` file.

But when I add it to `MainWindow` and run, it is blank. Here is my final code:

File `Theme/Generic.xaml`:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

File `CustomControl.cs`:

```
namespace Test
{
    public class CustomControl : TextBox
    {
        static CustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomControl)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you forgot to Initialize the control.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by using a custom control? For styling purposes you could use a style e.g. - composition over inheritance.

Comment: @macieqqq And how to initialize?

Comment: I want to extend the textbox control and add some UI logic like double click to edit. So I want to creat a custom control to reuse it anywhere.

Comment: If you want to just extend the logic maybe you can use Behavior class.

Comment: @macieqqq I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in it. It needs a template.

There are two ways to do that: First, easiest, base your `Style` on the default `TextBox` style. That'll give you the default template and everything else in the default style. Add setters at will to override the inherited ones, if you wish.

```
<Style 
    TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
    >
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

---

Second, write your own template. If you find that you need to do anything that the default template won't do for you, you'll be doing it this way. But beware, control behavior always turns out to be much more complicated than you would naively assume. These can be deep waters at times.

[Here's some documentation about retemplating a `TextBox` or a subclass of a `TextBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752068(v=vs.85).aspx).

You'll need to fill in a lot more properties than this, but here's a start:

```
<Style 
    TargetType="{x:Type local:MyCustomControl}" 
    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}"
    >
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
                <Border
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    >
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: It works. But by the way, could you tell me why the template property is compulsively needed?

Comment: @crupest See update. My first answer was what you would have to do if it were a completely original control, rather than a subclass of an existing control. If it's a subclass, you can usually inherit the default template instead.